# View javaScript datepicker everytime adding new row in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, css

I need some help. I am not really good in PHP & JavaScript. Below is my code. I want to view date picker every time I add new row. However, the result is not like what I want. Can someone help me to figure out what is my mistake and how to fix it? TQ.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Code</title>
<link type="text/css" href="css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.css" rel="stylesheet"    /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<form>
<div id="dates">        
<div>
<script>
$(function test1(){

// Datepicker
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
showOn: 'both',
buttonImageOnly: true,
buttonImage: 'calendar.gif',
buttonText: 'Calendar',
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
firstDay: 1, 
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});

$('#datepicker1').datepicker();
});
</script>
<label>Date 1</label>
<input type="text" name="datepicker1" id="datepicker1" />
</div>      
</div>
<div>
<input type="submit" id="submit1" value=" Add "/>
</div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
var dates = document.getElementById('dates'),
template = dates.getElementsByTagName('div'),
current = template.length,
max = 20;

template = template[0];

submit1.onclick = function () {
var new_field = template.cloneNode(true);
current += 1;
new_field.innerHTML = new_field.innerHTML.replace(/1/g, current);
dates.appendChild(new_field);   
return false;
};
document.body.appendChild(add_link);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsbin.com/IXofulic/2/edit

Comment: I don't think this code is valid

Comment: @user3106393 Can you post an example for the code? Like on jsbin.com or jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 1):

put your datepicker code in document ready state.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#datepicker1').datepicker();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple You have given a id to get the datepicker

```
$('#datepicker1').datepicker();
});
```

Rather use a Class name

```
$('.datepicker1').datepicker();
    });
```

Comment: I already try do it that why but it become worst. Even the 1st row cannot show the datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use Jquery date picker. It is easy and will fulfill your task.

Following the code you can use.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Add this in your form in HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="datepicker1" id="datepicker1" placeholder="Select Date" />
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
   $(function() {
   $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: The same problem still occur. I only show datepicker for the 1st row.